# ShortestPath with BFS (BreadthFirstSearch)

Tags: java, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I am trying to return the shortest path between two vertices for a graph. I have a code written to find the breadthFirstSearch but I do not know how to modify it to make it return the shortest path. Below is my breadthFirstSearch function

```
private void breadthFirstSearch(T start,T end){

    Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<T> visited = new HashSet<>();
    visited.add(start);
    queue.add(start);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        T v = queue.poll();
            for(int i =0;i<this.keyToVertex.get(v).successors.size();i++){                  if(visited.contains(this.keyToVertex.get(v).successors.get(i).key)){ 
                continue;
            }
            visited.add(this.keyToVertex.get(v).successors.get(i).key);
            queue.add(this.keyToVertex.get(v).successors.get(i).key);
        }

    }       

}
```

So how can I modify it to return the shortestpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track in `Queue` more than just a value to check, but the path leading to that value. So the type should be more than just `Queue<T>` but for example `Queue<LinkedList<T>>`.

The first value in the queue should the *singleton list* of `start` instead of just `start`.

As you process the values in the queue, vertex you're visiting will be the last element of the queue item, and when you add an item to the queue, it should be a clone of the current item, with the next neighbor added.

Something like this:

```
Queue<LinkedList<T>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.add(new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton(start)));

while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    LinkedList<T> path = queue.poll();
    T v = path.getLast();
    if (v.equals(end)) {
        return path;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.keyToVertex.get(v).successors.size(); i++) {
        T v2 = this.keyToVertex.get(v).successors.get(i).key;
        if (visited.contains(v2)) {
            continue;
        }

        LinkedList<T> path2 = new LinkedList<>(path);
        path2.add(v2);
        queue.add(path2);
        visited.add(v2);
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks! For future reference, I would want to get the last element in the LinkedList  rather than the first, because I am comparing it to the end vertex.

Comment: @Hussein I guess you mean that I used `peek()` instead of `getLast()`. I was under the impression that `peek()` would return the last (without checking the docs), apparently that was wrong. Corrected now, thanks for pointing out!